# create new instance of itemrenderer in MX DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I want to create new instance of item renderer for my data grid.

A single instance of your Item Renderer class (ListIR) is created for each visible item of the list-based control.
[image]

As the user scrolls through the items of a data grid control, Item Renderer instances are recycled rather than creating new instances.

[image]
But i would like to create new instance ..while scrollling item in datagrid.

any idea how to achieve it .

thanks in advance
javaamtho

Answer (score 0):

Set `useVirtualLayout` to `false` for your list. More information is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-1483ec4a12136246e76-8000.html#WS685c4ccbb85d340c6617851e121d4b8abae-8000).

Comment: thanks @Constantiner for your reply but i am using mx:datagrid control and this useVirtualLayout  property is not exists for datagrid ..:(

Comment: So tag `flex4` has no sense and only confuses. I'll remove it if you don't mind.

Comment: Ohh ..you could bcos i am developing it with SDK 4.0 ..thats why i added flex4 tag.

Comment: Then use the Spark Datagrid?  Also, Constantiner is right, but I feel that a warning should come with it.  Creating *new* item renderers for every scrolled data point is very wasteful and can lead to performance problems if you have a lot of rows.  Item renderer recycling is needed to reduce the amount of objects being created.